# Slow start up from cold start (20 minutes+), need help with logging all filesystem access with iotop

Tags: startup, disk-usage, iotop

Well in my development suit I notice that currently the boot up of the full suit takes a long (too long) time - about 20 to 25 minutes before I can actually use the applications.

The far majority (15-20) minutes it is busy "after" booting ubuntu. When I try to start the following applications:

- postgres docker
- pgadmin server
- postman
- webstorm for front end
- webstorm for backend
- flow server for both front and backend.
- react-scripts-npm real time file tracker and updater for front end

Now the problem is: there are no logs available on what is actually taking most time. I installed `iotop` application and run that using `sudo iotop -a -P` before loading the development suit. However that only shows the currently alive processes.

I can see webstorm and flow constantly starting child processes that actually show 98+% "IO" wait time, however these processes are really short lived (a few seconds at most) so they don't show up in the end.

Can I let iotop show a total log, including processes that died, over a period of time?

Comment: Is the 20 mins, from cold boot to desktop, or desktop to dev suite startup complete? If it's the later, can you start up one piece of dev suite at a time to determine which one may be causing the long startup time?

Comment: It's the total time, about 2-3 minutes it takes to get to the login, then 2 more before desktop becomes responsive after logging in. Then almost all time (about 15-20) it takes for webstorm & flow (which are wrought together in the webstorm IDE, they just show as separate processes) to load.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l` and `free -h` and `swapon` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Report back to @heynnema oh... and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.